# Python3: Telling a context manager to execute the code block more than once?

Tags: python-3.x, contextmanager

I'm wondering whether something is possible under `python3`. I would like to write a context manager which would execute its code block more than once. This doesn't seem to fit into the standard `python3` context manger semantics, but I'm wondering whether I'm missing something. I want something like the following:

```
CtxMgr(repeat_count=N, ... other args ...):
    # This is the code block.
    # This code block does whatever it needs to do,
    # and this context manager makes sure that it
    # runs `repeat_count` times.
```

I'm guessing that if such a thing is possible, it might be implementable somehow under a structure similar to this:

```
class CtxMgr(contextlib.AbstractContextManager):
    def __init__(self, repeat_count=1, *args, **kwargs):
        self.repeat_count = repeat_count
        ## etc.
    def __enter__(self):
        ## etc.
    def __exit__(self, *args):
        ## etc.
    ## What other method(s) would need to be implemented here?
```

I know that I can do the following, but I don't want to do it this way. I'm looking for a way to do this solely as a context manager.

```
# What I don't want to do ...

def func(... ...):
    # whatever

CtxMgr(repeat_count=3) as f:
    for _ in range(0, f.repeat_count):
        func(... ...)
```

In other words, I'm wondering whether this could somehow be accomplished in `python3` ***without*** the auxiliary function `func`, and for whatever code block follows the context manager instantiation, that code block would be automatically executed `repeat_count` times.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I also have tried doing this at some point, but it is not (currently) possible.  In my case I decided to use a decorator instead.

Comment: Thank you. Could you post an example of how you used a decorator for this purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment, this is not currently possible with a context manager.  However, you *can* use a decorator:

```
import functools
import time
from typing import Collection, Type, Union


def retry_n_times(n: int, *, sleep_secs: float = 0.0, retry_on: Union[Type[Exception], Collection[Type[Exception]]] = Exception):
    """
    Retry the decorated function up to `n` times.  Raise a RuntimeError if all attempts fail.
    If `sleep_secs` is specified, sleep that long after each attempt.
    If `retry_on` is specified, only retry on these exception types - other exceptions will escape as normal.
      By default, retry on any exception.
    """
    if n <= 0:
        raise ValueError("'n' must be >= 1")

    if not isinstance(retry_on, Collection):
        retry_on = [retry_on]
    retry_on = tuple(retry_on)

    def decorator(func):
        @functools.wraps(func)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            last_exception = None
            for _ in range(n):
                try:
                    return func(*args, **kwargs)
                except retry_on as exc:
                    last_exception = exc  # prevents "local variable 'exc' referenced before assignment"
                    if sleep_secs:
                        time.sleep(sleep_secs)
            else:
                raise RuntimeError(f'{func.__name__} failed {n} times') from last_exception

        return wrapper
    return decorator
```

Example usage:

```
count = 0

@retry_n_times(3)
def succeed_on_second_try():
    count += 1
    if count == 1:
        raise ValueError('Intentional failure')

succeed_on_second_try()
assert count == 2
```

Comment: This is close enough to what I want. I'm more interesed in the functionality itself, rather than specifically using a context manager. Thank you very much!